# Centralized configuration of settings for a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, group-policy

We'd like to develop a Google Chrome extension that is managed centrally, e.g. by MS Active Directory Group Policies.

How do we centrally distribute domain/customer specific *configuration* for such an extension?

Our users are mostly Windows users in the same domain, but we can not assume that they're logged in to any particular G-Suite organisation.

It does [seem possible](http://dennisspan.com/deploying-google-chrome-extensions-using-group-policy/) to create Active Directory Group Policies to *install* a particular extension for all users. That same article does however say:

> Unfortunately I was not able to come up with a solution concerning the centralized management of Chrome extension settings. Some extensions, for example [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en-US), come with additional options for the user to configure. As said, I was not able to find a way how to manage or configure these centrally.

So now that the extension is installed, how do we configure it?

Since it is our own extension, there is more freedom. I'm thinking with a Group Policy, one could install `C:\some\extension-file.json` and then run

```
google-chrome --headless file:///some/extension-file.json
```

If the extension intercepts that (as e.g. ViolentMonkey does) but only if it is a file:// URL, I guess that could be brought to work. But I'm hoping: Can you come up with something more elegant?

Comment: An extension must use chrome.storage.managed for this to work. Most extensions don't.

Comment: @wOxxOm: If you'd turn that into an answer, I'd accept it! Since it is our own extension, we could make sure it uses chrome.storage.managed.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you add an answer yourself with more details when you're done, as this is a somewhat complicated task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we centrally distribute domain/customer specific configuration for such an extension?

`chrome.storage.managed` is the specific answer for that need. Quoting the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#overview):

> Enterprise policies configured by the administrator for the extension can be read (using storage.managed with a schema).

With that in mind, you have to do the following:

1. [Provide a schema](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) for the storage via the `storage.managed_schema` key in the manifest. An example is given in the documentation.
2. Present values expected by the schema via GPO / registry as [described in admin docs](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions#TOC-Windows).

You can verify that the policy-mandated values are loaded by observing `chrome://policy`.

You can then use `chrome.storage.managed` as you would any other `chrome.storage` (though it is read-only), including watching for changes with `onChanged`.